# Data addition and updation in SQL tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam fairly new to SQLClient and all, and iam having a problem with my SQL tables..when ever i run my code, the data, rather than getting updated, attaches itself to the already existing records in the tables..here's my code

```
SqlConnection conneciones = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd;
conneciones.Open();
//put values into SQL DATABASE Table 1
for (int ok = 0; ok < CleanedURLlist.Length; ok++)
{
     cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into URL_Entries values('" + CleanedURLlist[ok] + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "' , '" + leak + "' )", conneciones);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conneciones.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert new records or update existing records?  Can you provide a sample of what table rows look like after you run this, and what you want them to look like?

Comment: BTW, use bound parameters to robustly handle any special characters that might be present in these "input variables" and to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Comment: Iam trying to Insert the values, and then after insertion i want the values in the table to get updated rather than add the new values to the already existing values in the table..can you give me an example of update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these functions, i hope you understand better on update , insert and delete functions..

Code snippets for reading, inserting, updating and deleting a records using asp.net and c# and sql server  database

```
  static void Read()
  {
    try
    {
      string connectionString =
            "server=.;" +
            "initial catalog=employee;" +
            "user id=sa;" +
            "password=sa123";
        using (SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails", conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id = ", reader["Id"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Name = ", reader["Name"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Address = ", reader["Address"]);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}

static void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
            "server=.;" +
            "initial catalog=employee;" +
            "user id=sa;" +
            "password=sa123";
        using (SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES(" +
                   "@Id, @Name, @Address)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Amal Hashim");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", "Bangalore");

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //rows number of record got inserted
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}

static void Update()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
            "server=.;" +
            "initial catalog=employee;" +
            "user id=sa;" +
            "password=sa123";
        using (SqlConnection conn = ew SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE EmployeeDetails SET Name=@NewName, Address=@NewAddress WHERE Id=@Id", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Munna Hussain");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", "Kerala");

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //rows number of record got updated
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}

static void Delete()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
            "server=.;" +
            "initial catalog=employee;" +
            "user id=sa;" +
            "password=sa123";
        using (SqlConnection conn = ew SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM EmployeeDetails " +
                    "WHERE Id=@Id", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //rows number of record got deleted
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i tried the update example given in this..apparently it gives a couple of exceptions..here's the code:

Comment: @ShahvezIrfan where is the code that you have tried...what exceptions you are getting.....

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE URL_Entries SET URL=@NewURL, Date=@NewDate" + "WHERE Crawl_ID=@NewCrawl_ID", conneciones);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crawl_ID", ok);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", CleanedURLlist[ok]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: iam sorry it has to be in this format..doesn't let me post in tags

Comment: oh..yes but now iam getting the exception: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: yes..iam getting the exception: 
[SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.]

Comment: put a break point at each of those lines  and try in debug mode that will show you on which line is giving that error ....

Comment: @ShahvezIrfan that error means you are trying to update the column with a string larger than it can hold.  For example, if your url column is `varchar(50)` and the value is 100 characters, you'll get this exception.

Comment: Thank you! it works now..the only issue is that iam not getting any values in my table like i was with the Insert command...i open the table and i get null values..any idea there?

Comment: @ShahvezIrfan well thats depends upon how you are entering the values in page(.aspx)......

Comment: The insert query appends the same data in the rows when the code is run the second time..how do i use update to first populate the table with the values, and then when i run the code again with the updated values, it should replace the values initially inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `INSERT` function, that is 'ADD NEW RECORDS'

If you want an update, you'll want an `UPDATE` function

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET column1 = 'x', column2 = 'y' 
WHERE id = z
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inserting new records, but I'm not clear on whether it is not doing that, or you mean to update existing records.

Aside from that, understanding that you are new to working with SQL Server, there are a couple of things you should be aware of.

1. You should use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to automatically dispose resources.  This will also close your connection for you so you don't have open connections hanging around.
2. You should use parameters to protect against [sql injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) attacks.  Another benefit of using parameters in your case is that you don't need to create new commands for every statement.

For example:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "insert into URL_Entries values(@url, @now, @leak)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now", DateTime.Now);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lead", leak);

    // update to correspond to your definition of the table column
    var urlParameter = command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@url", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));

    connection.Open();

    for (int ok = 0; ok < CleanedURLlist.Length; ok++)
    {
        urlParameter.Value = CleanedURLlist[ok];
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

---

Per your comment, if you want to do an update, you'll need to include the parameter(s) that identify the rows to update.  If this is a single row, use the primary key value:

```
command.CommandText = "update URL_Entries set UrlColumn = @url, ModifiedDate = @now where ID = @id";
```